# how to get the position of the cursor in an editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function that tracks the cursor position in an editable div:

```
  function getCaretPosition(editableDiv) {
        var caretPos = 0, containerEl = null, sel, range;
        if (window.getSelection) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.rangeCount) {
                range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == editableDiv) {
                    caretPos = range.endOffset;
                }
            }
        } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
            range = document.selection.createRange();
            if (range.parentElement() == editableDiv) {
                var tempEl = document.createElement("span");
                editableDiv.insertBefore(tempEl, editableDiv.firstChild);
                var tempRange = range.duplicate();
                tempRange.moveToElementText(tempEl);
                tempRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", range);
                caretPos = tempRange.text.length;
            }
        }
        return caretPos-1;
    }
```

The issue is that if my editable div has the following html:

```
hello <span contenteditable='false'>Abderrahmane Benbachir</span>
```

and I put the cursor next to the span, it starts counting the cursor from 0. Why is this? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, to get the caret position use this [**Tim Down's code**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13950376) instead. Which also has `restoreSelection` function in it which restores the caret position.

I asked the same question recently, which you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16331088/1577396).

Comment: I don't understand how that code is supposed to help that problem. That Tim Down's code doesn't have a solution/function for finding the caret position.. please elaborate

Comment: Are you also saying that I'd have to call restoreSelection ?

Comment: @adit yes. The code which I provided has a function called `restoreSelection`. use that.  (I am average in english so please ask again if you can't understand).

Comment: thanks for helping out. In my case what should I pass into the restoreSelection function?

Comment: Sorry, `_savedSel = saveSelection(this);`  where `this` is the reference of editable div.

Comment: @adit saveSelection is another function in the same provided code.